# Abrir grandes imagens com python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, buffer

Estou trabalhando em um software que processa imagens muito grandes, entre 10GB e 30GB. As imagens são muito pesadas para abrir de uma vez. Eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de usar o OpenCV para abrir a imagem em partes, como se dividisse ela em dez partes, aplicando os filtros uma parte por vez, e no final juntando tudo em uma imagem processada.

Eu sei que para isso seria necessário alguma forma de Buffer. Alguém pode me ajudar? Eu não tenho exemplos de código pois é uma dúvida apenas e eu nem sei como fazer.

Comment: A Opencv sozinha não é capaz de carregar uma imagem maior de 4GB e se conseguisse iria tomar 4GB de memoria RAM do seu O.S. https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/1438 https://github.com/introlab/find-object/issues/66 A comunidade costuma usar outra lib para carregar imagens grandes ou cortar as imagens em pequenos arquivos numerados e ai processar estes em sequência. http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#crop_tile

Comment: Uma alternativa é o [scikit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31951507/7690982).